# Proper Contact Deletion Methods

Tags: marketing-cloud

I've sourced quite a few resources on contact deletion and can't find one that works. I've tried creating a contact deletion data extension and then after deletion, the contacts still exists, even when creating test subjects that I know can be accounted for as a single contact. Is there a resource for properly deleting contacts so that I can get counts under for billing purposes? Looking to delete about 20K records.

Thank you for any insight

Comment: Are you using MC Connect? Do you delete your contacts from the CRM as well so they don't fall back after the deletion process? Keep in mind that contacts are deleted only from Sendable Data Extensions, therefore, you should delete contacts from non-sendable data extensions manually

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't have any problems using the the standard [**Contact Builder deletion**](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_cab_contact_deletion.htm&type=5) method, so before you try that again - check for the follow:

**1)** Under Contacts Configuration click on Manage Settings and check if the amount of days is 0 or 1 to get them removed quick, as by default this will be 14 days.

**2)** In case you are using MC Connect and are synchronising your Leads/Contacts then make sure these Contacts are already deleted on your Sales Cloud, otherwise they will just be reimported back.

**3)** Understand that it will only work and clean **sendable** Data Extensions, so if you have kept those Contacts in backup or other non-sendable Data Extensions then you will need to clean those up later manually (although they are already removed from the AllContacts and should not count as billable Contacts anymore)

- [**Contact Deletion best practices**](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_cab_best_practices.htm&type=5)

Comment: Thank you, do you know what or how that contact is deleted? For example, is it taking that subscriber key in the deletion data extension and then purging the contact record based off that subscriber key or some other identifier? I will try this method again.

Comment: If you are using SubscriberKey as your ContactKey - and deleting that Data Extension via the official Contact Deletion method (under Contact Builder > All Contacts) then yes, this will work. Pay attention to AllContacts table numbers. 
To see progress of deletion click on the same trash-can icon and 'View pending deletions'. Only once it's complete you can try searching for the Contact in AllContact table. If it's gone > congratulations, the deletion worked.